# Making type trait work for all derived types

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++-concepts, base-class

I have a type trait and concept which checks if an `std::variant` can hold a given type `T`. Now I have a type `variant2` which derives from `std::variant`, and I want to use that type trait with the new `variant2` type. How can I accomplish this elegantly?

This doesn't work ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXLaY9o4CdQ0ERRHRsXoK9Y3NOW0jvf0lZRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm24Abg14hgRH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8cjxKHA17cPZtsMuy8ByObic70wrG%2B90eAOerzcaABmCSBAUUN%2B/0BwOOBAAnklMAB9AjEJiENGbG7Q%2B4ETAsJIGWkgvEE5hsfYAFVI%2BxZjFYLwAaudLuj3l4HPszh9LsT8ZgjlZqXdafTGfKcXK2S8uTzNfyAHSG/Z3YjAClUu5iiVSi6CWUEkE6kboEAgG0i44ms2G/XfSmHe77IP7ED7JJeKK0PDIfbO134BTaLwAroMEFxkB4BSEhT8x3cr3mn3XQ4AdispYAIgqfj8VQymEyNaz%2BZzubytfshdLBOjEWsUfss4T3Xbea9K5LhWO5fmu9OrpTXWdvOrFQ8aXSG7T4R2DUaOeaflaCFOewQzCGwxGozGM6PF25D8X/SZy7WqzWlQ%2BzOmCC6QBYARUnqWluVCAhuSiVBPG5DN3k%2BEspS/Dc7gg/YWDJBgIHmMt12DfYvDSIxOQnWN/1dBCjBQn4CLwKh9kREZMFUJJiH2CBhwfe11SfbksF2XkICleZrlwt98II4MMzQLxTxBEFDjMMwAHUSAAa0wdAwDAcxLwU45yIA1xaBQgi32raEqw4RZaE4ABWXg/A4LRSFQTg3GsaxY2WVYXi2HhSAITQbMWdSQHsjR9E4SQnJCtzOF4BQQCi4KXJs0g4FgGBEBQVB6ToWJyEoNACvoOJgC4TY2iwE5o0wAU8EwAB3AB5VlOECmhaFpYhkogKJ4qiUIGlxTreGG5hiFxVqom0ao0sC0q2EEVqGFoMb0tILAoi8YA3DEWhku4XgsEwoxxC2/BiAWvATkwY7XJY6o5PWVyII6eKoyiUlpo8LB4pJPAWHGxYqAMM1Gpa9rGHGmRBBEMR2CkeH5CUNR4t0NoDCMFAvMsfQ8CiZLIEWVAUQyY6AFpnSOStTEsawzA0fYqdahReFQe7iA%2BLASZw9pOgyFwGHcTwWj0YJQgGUohjaFI0lTcZWjyRWMhmQY4kmDpbu6UYmnFiZBd1hgekaDXZa12x9eV4Z9YtuYuEWBRfLWBZoo4RzSGc1z3I4fZVAADgANip4PJH2YBkBjKr9S4DjcEIEglOq%2BZeDSrR5jCiKorsjhYtIEH7MkfVJHiUt4g0Cuy4rqvEh9znEtsFKgpCxYsty5YCHDSCKAgUqkkK4hwn5Tgg9D8PI%2Bj/ZY8CrSk95vR%2BAR0RxBR5e0ZUdQtqx0hmtJJJQY9r2G4SjhWrknv9lQBjx7DiOo5jzY444jwytiFOnfTtvFgQCEsDiALPOBcQaSHsvqSKzN4jM0gRoaBbRT5%2BySi3DOoVSDhUih7TYcUtpINbulLOHszA4N9k3VBhDuZpGcJIIAA)):

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename Variant>
struct variant_type;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct variant_type<T, std::variant<Args...>> 
    : public std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Args>...> {};

template<typename T, typename Variant>
concept is_variant_type = variant_type<T, Variant>::value;

template <typename... Ts>
struct variant2 : public std::variant<Ts...> {
};

variant2<std::monostate, int, bool, std::string> var;

int main() {
    using T = std::string;

    if constexpr (is_variant_type<T, decltype(var)>) {
        std::cout << "Worked!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

"Worked" never appears on the screen which is obvious because the default type trait is SFINAED.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just fix your specialization by expressing that your template must inherit from `std::variant`

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

template <typename T, typename Variant>
struct variant_type;

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Var, typename... Args>
struct variant_type<T, Var<Args...>>
    : public std::conjunction<
          std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Args>...>,
          std::is_base_of<std::variant<Args...>, Var<Args...>>> {};

template <typename T, typename Variant>
concept is_variant_type = variant_type<T, Variant>::value;

template <typename... Ts>
struct variant2 : public std::variant<Ts...> {};

variant2<std::monostate, int, bool, std::string> var;

int main() {
    using T = std::string;

    if constexpr (is_variant_type<T, decltype(var)>) {
        std::cout << "Worked!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I just added a conjunction to achieve that and we'are done.
[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/b9dT77dr5)
[EDIT] sorry, it's just a bit more complicated: I added a template template parameter that implies that your inherited class has exactly the same template parameters than the base one, which might be restrictive.

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76457957/21691539) is more generic as it make no assumption about the inherited class template parameters, it merely express that it is convertible to a variant and will retrieve its parameters.<br>
Perhaps that an improvement, would be to mix both answer and enforcing that the ```variant2``` class is indeed inherited from ```std::variant``` thus excluding class that would be implicitly convertible to your ```std::variant``` (yet I don't know exactly to do that without knowing ```Args...```).

Comment: it would be very easy to adjust it, by using `std::is_convertible` instead of `std::is_base_of`, and I would also find that solution preferable. I'd also change the names of `variant_type` and `is_variant_type` to `is_variant_type` and `is_variant_type_v` respectively, to follow the standard trait naming conventions.

Comment: @JanSchultke What name then would you suggest for the concept?

Comment: @glades concepts in the standard library usually don't have any suffix and also don't start with `is_`, so the concept should just be `variant_type`, or perhaps `variant_type_in`.

Comment: @JanSchultke Indeed, I got it twisted, thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `variant2` inherits `std::variant`, you can extract its base `variant` type through the following helper function

```
template<typename... Args>
auto as_variant(const std::variant<Args...>&) -> std::variant<Args...>;

template<typename T>
struct to_variant;

template<typename T>
  requires requires (const T& t) { as_variant(t); }
struct to_variant<T> {
  using type = decltype(as_variant(std::declval<const T&>()));
};
```

Then slightly modify the `is_variant_type` concept

```
template<typename T, typename Variant>
concept is_variant_type = 
  variant_type<T, typename to_variant<Variant>::type>::value;
```

Or more simply, just define `is_variant_type` directly as

```
template<typename T, typename Variant>
concept is_variant_type = requires (const Variant& var) {
  []<typename... Args>(const std::variant<Args...>&) 
    requires (std::same_as<T, Args> || ...)
  { }(var);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5T5qqc4jc)